# with Groovy Console, is it possible to reload changed files in classpath?

Tags: groovy, groovy-console

I often want to test methods I'm developing in a Groovy class independently, and use the Console to do so, like:

```
groovyConsole -cp mygroovyfiles
```

However I have not yet been able to figure out how to reload changes to my groovy files so that I can update the files and see the results reflected in the Console. "/Script/Add Directory to ClassPath" and "Script/Clear Script Context" don't work. Is this possible?

Comment: I have strange problems with menu "add JARs to classpath" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32494835/what-is-classpath-for-groovy-console-jdbc-driver-prblem?noredirect=1#comment52852295_32494835

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe it is possible in the groovyConsole.  The groovysh, however, is a different story.  The groovysh has a \l command which lets you reload a script.  I don't know if this helps you, but it works for me.  A session would look like this...

```
bobk-mbp:~ bobk$ cd work/workspace/ZGroovyProject/
bobk-mbp:ZGroovyProject bobk$ emacs src/Hello.groovy 
bobk-mbp:ZGroovyProject bobk$ groovysh
Groovy Shell (1.8.3, JVM: 1.6.0_29)
Type 'help' or '\h' for help.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
groovy:000> \l src/Hello.groovy 
hello, world.
===> null
groovy:000> \l src/Hello.groovy 
hello, world from bob
===> null
groovy:000>
```

Comment: Have yet to hear anyone else say it's possible so I guess not.  groovysh should fit my needs, I'll check it out.

Comment: Only works for scripts, not compiled classes loaded from the classpath (as far as I can tell).  :purge didn't help either.

Answer (score 2):

You may try to clean your buffer before you reload the script

```
>clear
>load src/Hello.groovy
```