# What is classpath for Groovy Console / jdbc driver prblem?

Tags: groovy, groovy-console

Such database code is OK in Java environment (without binded value 'c'), but in Groovy console can't properly use jdbc, with exception

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=
```

Driver class is known for script (is loaded without null etc) but probably not registered in Drivermanager ?

code (i try with and without `Class.forname()` )

```
import groovy.sql.Sql
import groovy.sql.DataSet

c =   Class.forName('com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver')

def db = [url:'jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=... ,driver:'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver']
 def sql = Sql.newInstance(db )
```

EDIT:
what I had checked already:

1. fresh started Groovy console hasn't sqljdbc4.jar on classpath.

Natural exception `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` on line 4 `Class.forName()`, or if line 4 commented and parameters db with driver name the exception on line 7  `Sql.newInstance(db )`

Its logical, driver class not found etc ...

1a. if db parameters with 3 arguments (without driver), I assume its legal (and working in other situations) exception changes to `SQLException: No suitable driver` on line 7   `Sql.newInstance(db )`

It is logical too, DriverManager don't know how to resolve key `jdbc:sqlserver` . Driver isn't registered and DriverManager have not magical knowledge what class implements.

2.
when I add jar to console classpath (Script / Add jar(s) to classpath) things are somewhat changed. No more `ClassNotFoundException` and variable `c` has non-null value (driver class) but `SQLException: No suitable driver` continues.

My understanding of JDBC philosophy: (modern) JAR driver uses technique with file `META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver` to be known for `DriverManager`.
So in correct situation 4th argument (driver class name) is not required because is discovered automatically.
Please correct my understanding if I'm wrong.

I have used word 'active' in this sense ("non active" means class exist and is loaded, but can be used as jdbc driver).

My maximal code is:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql
import groovy.sql.DataSet
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.util.ServiceLoader;


c =   Class.forName('com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver')
DriverManager.getDrivers()
ServiceLoader.load(java.sql.Driver.class)
def db = [url:'jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;...,driver:'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver']
def sql = Sql.newInstance(db )
```

but still `no suitable driver` Exception

EDIT2:
I enumerate things with such code (before newInstance() ):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String grVersion = "brak";

        Enumeration<Driver> dri = DriverManager.getDrivers();

        for (Enumeration<Driver> e = dri; e.hasMoreElements();) {
            Driver e1 = e.nextElement();
            sb.append(e1.getClass().getName()).append(' ');
            sb.append(e1.getMajorVersion()).append('.').append(e1.getMinorVersion());
        }


        // get LOADED drivers niesetty

        ServiceLoader<java.sql.Driver> codecSetLoader = ServiceLoader.load(java.sql.Driver.class);
        for (Driver e1 : codecSetLoader) {
            sb.append(e1.getClass().getName()).append('!');
            sb.append(e1.getMajorVersion()).append('.').append(e1.getMinorVersion());
            sb.append("# ");
        }
```

and get

```
com.mysql.jdbc.Driver 5.1com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver 5.1com.mysql.jdbc.Driver!5.1# com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver!5.1# com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver!4.0#  
Exception thrown

java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=....

    at ConsoleScript11.run(ConsoleScript11:32)
```

My (basic) code executed is Tomcat environment still working ok. What's the matter?

Comment: Is the driver jar on the classpath?

Comment: Yes, is present (loaded with not null) but "not activated"

Comment: I don't know what that means :-(

Comment: If you did add the jar with the jdbc driver on the classpath of your Groovy console, then it should have worked. I too don't mean what "not activated"means here

Comment: I made update to the question

Answer (score 1):

Autor's answer:

When driver JAR is added "dynamic" from menu (like written over) is visible but not working as JDBC.

When driver JAR is dropped into ...console\lib catalogue (between other JAR'a of Groovy) all OK.

This level of investigation is enough for me, maybe someone try to find bug in menu. Can I accept (green) my own answer?

Answer (score 1):

Solution for today, is add the following at beginning of script. Using groovy 2.5.

```
@Grab('com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc4:4.0')
@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader=true)
```