# No suitable driver found for jdbc:jtds:sqlserver in grails 2.4.3 + groovy 2.3 project

Tags: grails, groovy, jtds

I am facing weird issue in my grail project and after trying a lot i am posting this question here.I have tried all the URL related combination form  http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html#noSuitableDriver and other stack over flow answers like [Help me create a jTDS connection string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862283/help-me-create-a-jtds-connection-string).

I am working on grails 2.4.3 project with groovy 2.3 and trying to connect with SQL Server database using jtds 1.3.1 but always getting "No suitable driver found for jdbc:jtds:sqlserver:" But to test this scenario i have written stand alone program as given below for same data base using same jar jtds 1.3.1 and its working fine.

```
try{
                Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
                String url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<hostname>:<port>/<database>";
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"user","password");

                Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);}
```

Below I have provided the grails project code snippet for connection class

```
class SQLServerConnection implements DBConnection {

@Override
public Connection getConnection(String serverName, String databaseName) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
    String url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<host>:<port>/<database>";
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"user","password"); 
    return con

}
```

Action form where i am calling this method

```
def dataFaucetColumn (){
    def currentApp = RawDataApp.get(params.int('id'))
    String query = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME ='"+currentApp?.tableName +"'"
    Connection con = new SQLServerConnection().getConnection(currentApp?.servers,currentApp?.databaseName)
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query); }
```

waiting for your answers.

Comment: connected or not, in context groovy console: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32494835/what-is-classpath-for-groovy-console-jdbc-driver-prblem/32507453#32507453

Comment: I have googled a hour. Groovy has sometimes `"No suitable driver found for ... "` in selected context of use I use Java almost 14yers and see such exception very rarely

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can use SQL Server with Grails, while taking advantage of Hibernate:

1. Open *grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy*
2. In the dependencies section add the JTDS dependency. Then save the file.

**Example:**

```
dependencies {
    runtime 'net.sourceforge.jtds:jtds:1.3.1'       

}
```

3. Open *grails-app/conf/DataSource.groovy*
4. In the environments section, set up the data source and save the file. In the following example I'll set up SQL Server for the production environment

**Example:**

```
environments {
    production {
         dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<hostname>:<port>/<database>"
            username = "X"
            password = "X"
            driverClassName = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
            dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
            properties {
                maxActive = 8 
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 1800000
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 1800000
                numTestsPerEvictionRun = 3
                testOnBorrow = true
                testWhileIdle = true
                testOnReturn = true
                validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
                validationQueryTimeout = 3
                validationInterval = 15000
               jdbcInterceptors = "ConnectionState"
               defaultTransactionIsolation = java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
             }
         }
     }
}
```

That's it. Now you can use GORM to query the database. Plus, Hibernate will manage the database connection(s) :)

Comment: Thanks for information, But my problem is to take data base parameter dynamically from front end and connect to database,putting data base entry in DataSource.groovy file wouldn't help me much.