# Attempting to configure grails app in MS sql server

Tags: grails

In lib i'm adding *jar(jtds:1.2.6.jar)* file . 
But it's getting an error like:

> cannot load your jar file

**sql.groovy :**

```
package com
class Sql {

    String project

    String title

    static constraints = {

        project blank:false

        title blank:false
    }
}

Datasource.groovy

dataSource {

 pooled = true

     driverClassName = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.driver"
    username = "sa"
    password = ""
    dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect"
}

hibernate {

    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
}

// environment specific settings

environments {

    development {

        dataSource {

            dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
      url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://ASIA-IN-GJVX022:1433;databaseName=Haritha;instance=SQLEXPRESS"
        }

    }
    test {

        dataSource {

            dbCreate = "update"

            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
        }
    }
    production {

        dataSource {

            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:h2:prodDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
            pooled = true
            properties {
               maxActive = -1
               minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=1800000
               timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=1800000
               numTestsPerEvictionRun=3
               testOnBorrow=true
               testWhileIdle=true
               testOnReturn=true
               validationQuery="SELECT 1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is it possible that your jar is corrupted? can you re-download and place it on `lib` folder..

Comment: that also i tried but it's not working

Comment: i re-downloaded the jar file and placed in lib folder but still it shows can not load jdbc file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32531566/no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcjtdssqlserver-in-grails-2-4-3-groovy-2-3-pr/32532946#32532946