# Cannot connect to DB2 from Groovy

Tags: sql, groovy, db2

I’m trying to open an SQL instance within a driver which uses the DB2Driver from IBM.

The interesting part is that when I include:

```
def DB2Driver = new DB2Driver()
```

That initializes just fine.

But when I do

```
 Sql.newInstance(info.getHost(), info.getConnectionMetaData().getParameterValue('username'), info.getConnectionMetaData().getParameterValue('password'), info.getConnectionMetaData().getParameterValue('driverClass'))
```

Or

```
Sql.newInstance(info.getHost(), info.getConnectionMetaData().getParameterValue('username'), info.getConnectionMetaData().getParameterValue('password'), 'com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver')
```

It will fail to open a SQL connection, saying that a suitable driver isn't found. How can I get the connection to DB2 to open?

Comment: Are you using Grape (ex. `@Grab()`) to handle the dependency on the DB2 jdbc drivers?

Comment: Problem has some similarity to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32494835/what-is-classpath-for-groovy-console-jdbc-driver-prblem

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using a groovy script with `@Grab` and `@Grapes` annotations, you probably need [configure `Grape` for JDBC drivers](http://groovy-lang.org/grape.html#Grape-JDBCDrivers):

> Because of the way JDBC drivers are loaded, you’ll need to configure Grape to attach JDBC driver dependencies to the system class loader

In [`groovy.sql.Sql`](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/subprojects/groovy-sql/src/main/java/groovy/sql/Sql.java) the JDBC `DriverManager` is used to get a connection: `DriverManager.getConnection()`. Since it needs the driver depencencies attached to the system class loader, you need to do it with [`@GrabConfig`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/GrabConfig.html).

For example, this script

```
@Grapes([
  @Grab(group='org.hsqldb', module='hsqldb', version='2.3.2'),
])

import groovy.sql.Sql

def sql = Sql.newInstance('jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb', 'sa', '', 'org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver')

println 'SQL connection ready'
```

fails with the exception `java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb`, but with

```
@Grapes([
  @Grab(group='org.hsqldb', module='hsqldb', version='2.3.2'),
  @GrabConfig(systemClassLoader=true)
])
```

it works perfectly.